# How to move row from one table to another with no FK connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am doing Entity Framework and I have a database where there is no connection between the two tables. My form has two datagridviews each showing the contents of those tables on load. I also have two buttons. When I select any cell (which selects the entire row) on the sport table and click copy, it moves the data to the health table and removes it from the sport one. The second button does vice versa. What do you think is wrong?

I have tried delete and add and there seems to be a validation error. How can I fix this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SportsAreUsEntities mySports = new SportsAreUsEntities();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshGrids();
    }

    private void RefreshGrids()
    {
        var allSport = from eachSport in mySports.SportingItems                          
                       orderby eachSport.SportingItemID ascending
                       select new
                       {
                           eachSport.SportingItemID,
                           eachSport.Name,
                           eachSport.Description,
                           eachSport.QuantityOnHand
                       };

        dataGridSport.DataSource = allSport.ToList();

        var allHealth = from eachHealth in mySports.HealthItems
                        orderby eachHealth.HealthItemID ascending
                        select new
                        {
                            eachHealth.HealthItemID,
                            eachHealth.Name,
                            eachHealth.Description,
                            eachHealth.QuantityOnHand
                        };

        dataGridHealth.DataSource = allHealth.ToList();
    }

    private void moveToHealth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve selected row and id
        var selectedRow = dataGridSport.CurrentRow;
        int selectedID = (int)selectedRow.Cells["SportingItemID"].Value;
        var data2 = new HealthItem();


        var rowToDelete =        (from row in mySports.SportingItems
                                  where row.SportingItemID == selectedID
                                  select row).Single();

        var rowToAdd = (from row in mySports.SportingItems
                           where row.SportingItemID == selectedID
                           select row).Single();
        mySports.SportingItems.Remove(rowToDelete);  //Mark for deletion   
        mySports.HealthItems.Add(data2);
        mySports.SaveChanges();
        RefreshGrids();



    }
```

Comment: Show your code/what you have tried.

Comment: @williamXifaras I have updated my question with my code any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you say 'it doesn't seem to work', what exactly is happening at the moment?  does the page crash? does the page do nothing and stare at you?

Comment: also, you might have to remap the properties, because SportingItemID and HealthItemID (even though they're both ints) entity framework is going to have a problem with the property names of those models' going into the database